# How to incorporate svg in a React component?

Tags: css, reactjs, web, svg

Here is the svg of the icon:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 128 128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <style>.cls-1{fill:#4d91bb;}.cls-2{fill:#2175aa;}.cls-3{fill:#c3edf5;}.cls-4{fill:#7ad0cb;}.cls-5{fill:#4dbab4;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title />
    <g data-name="23 Page Rank Badge" id="_23_Page_Rank_Badge">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M43.22,61,64,73,40,114.53,35.65,98.07l-16.43,4.46Zm41.57,0L64,73l24,41.57,4.35-16.46,16.43,4.46Z" />
        <polygon class="cls-2" points="39.48 67.43 39.48 81.48 55.02 81.48 57.59 84.06 64 72.97 43.22 60.97 39.48 67.43" />
        <polygon class="cls-2" points="92.52 74.36 84.78 60.97 64 72.97 71.87 86.6 76.98 81.48 92.52 81.48 92.52 74.36" />
        <rect class="cls-3" height="53.03" width="53.03" x="37.48" y="24.45" />
        <rect class="cls-3" height="53.03" transform="translate(54.78 -30.33) rotate(45)" width="53.03" x="37.48" y="24.45" />
        <circle class="cls-4" cx="64" cy="50.97" r="15" />
        <path class="cls-5" d="M52.74,51A15,15,0,0,1,65.87,36.09a15,15,0,1,0,0,29.74A15,15,0,0,1,52.74,51Z" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Here's the component I made but it's not showing the icon :(

```js
const RankSVG = ({
    width = "53" ,
    height = "53"  , 
    viewBox="0 0 128 128"  ,

}) => {

    return(
    <>
        <svg viewBox={viewBox} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <style>{`.cls-1{fill:#4d91bb}.cls-2{fill:#2175aa}.cls-3{fill:#c3edf5}.cls-4{fill:#7ad0cb}.cls-5{fill:#4dbab4}`}</style>
        <path className="cls-1" d="M43.22,61,64,73,40,114.53,35.65,98.07l-16.43,4.46Zm41.57,0L64,73l24,41.57,4.35-16.46,16.43,4.46Z" /><polygon className="cls-2" points="39.48 67.43 39.48 81.48 55.02 81.48 57.59 84.06 64 72.97 43.22 60.97 39.48 67.43" /><polygon className="cls-2" points="92.52 74.36 84.78 60.97 64 72.97 71.87 86.6 76.98 81.48 92.52 81.48 92.52 74.36" /><rect className="cls-3" height={height} width={width} x="37.48" y="24.45" /><rect className="cls-3" height={height} transform="translate(54.78 -30.33) rotate(45)" width={width} x="37.48" y="24.45" /><circle className="cls-4" cx="64" cy="50.97" r="15" /><path className="cls-5" d="M52.74,51A15,15,0,0,1,65.87,36.09a15,15,0,1,0,0,29.74A15,15,0,0,1,52.74,51Z" /></svg>
    </>
    );
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? if I want to include such svgs in future, what points should I remember to avoid making mistakes?

Comment: The literal object your component gets at the beginning looks unusual.

Comment: that may not matter , please tell me how to view this component

Comment: https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/1688850/badge_page_quality_rank_icon  . Link for the icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move your styles out of to `.jsx` file into your `.css` file. The curly braces `{}` that separate classes interfere with .jsx `{}` which are intended for expressions.

**Here's a working sample:** https://codesandbox.io/s/718w386v46

Now, alternatively, you could keep your styles in the .jsx file but then you have to define them as object literals with an additional set of curly braces inside the  curly braces that are intended for expressions.